# 7za a readarchivename

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following problem: I'd like to write a bash script that reads the name of a single file with extension .jpg in the same folder and use it as an archive name.

```
/Sample.jpg
/Sample.7z <--

ls *jpg > OutputFileName
...
7za a Sample.7z ...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the script going to add just "Sample.jpg" to the "Sample.7z" archive? (you used ellipsis, so it's not clear).

Comment: @JeffSchaller it will add another reference folder. For me not the contents of the .7z file but the name is important. Sorry for naming both things Sample. I meant NameOfJpeg.jpg should be used to create NameOfJpeg.7z ...Your explanation below made it clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple shell parameter expansion to solve this -- no bash features necessary:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- *.jpg
if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ "$1" = "*.jpg" ]
then
  echo "Error: there is not exactly one .jpg file here"
  exit 1
fi

7za a "${1%.jpg}".7z "$1" # ...
```

The script sets the positional parameters to the expanded wildcard `*.jpg`. If there isn't exactly one such resulting filename, it exits with an error. The second half of the test there is for the situation where (using plain sh) the wildcard does not match *any* files, and so remains unexpanded as the literal "`*.jpg`" string. If you're using bash, you can remove that second check while adding `shopt -s nullglob` ahead of the `set` command to cause the wildcard to be *removed* during expansion if it does not match anything.

Once we have that one matching file, call `7za` and give the archive name via parameter expansion, which strips the trailing ".jpg" and then appends ".7z".

Comment: Jeff, thank you for the detailed explanation. It works like a charm. In my case there is for sure only 1 .jpg file so no need for that check but you're awesome!